# Lower bound for $(x + y)^k $?

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, exponentiation

I'm wondering, is there a lower bound for $(x + y)^k $?
For example, if $x,y,k > 0$, can we say that $(x + y)^k  \geq x^k + y^k$? If anyone has a source/reference for this, that would be great.

Comment: Is $k$ an integer? Then just use $$ (x+y)^k = \sum_{n=0}^k \binom kn x^{k-n}y^n$$ and the fact that all summands are non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $k \in \Bbb N$.
$$(x+y)^k = \sum_{i=0}^k \binom k i x^iy^{k-i}$$
When $x, y > 0$, all the $\binom k i x^iy^{k-i} > 0$, so indead
$$(x+y)^k \ge x^k+y^k$$

Comment: What if $k \not\in \mathbb{Z}$? Seems like a rather large assumption (and the inequality isn't strict for $k=1$ either).

Comment: And this isn't true anyway, for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, since (taking $k=-1$) $1/(x+y)$ is obviously not greater than $1/x+1/y$ for all $x,y>0$ ...

Comment: Oh, I meant to write $k \in \mathbb N$ and $\ge$. The assumption is just based on a pure guess, that this is what the enquirer is looking for.

Comment: It is interesting to note that when generalizing to $k \in \mathbb{R}$, it doesn't work for $k \leq 1$ (e.g. $x=y=2$, $k=1/2$, in which case we get $2$ for the left hand side and $2\sqrt{2}$ for the right hand side). You can generalize your answer to the reals using what you've already done with the integers, and applying the fact (with proof perhaps?) that $(x+y)^k$ is continuous and [monotonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) in $k$.